Why was Amaia seeing the dead girl?
In The Boarding School: Las Cumbres, Amaia and Ines could both see dead bodies. Ines had a reason, or there was a reason why she saw them, because of the connection to her past.
Why was Amaia seeing the dead girl? I understand why Ines saw them, but I don't know why Amaia saw them. Does anybody know why?
